# Adjust color settings

Tags: 14.04, color-management

I am looking for a nice and simple way to adjust screen colours. Redshift seems to do it so it is certainly possible. Is there a utility which gives some Red, Green, Blue scroll bars to adjust screen colours? So far what I have found (colormgr, Argyll CMS) all look too complicated to use and can't get my tiny head around those.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a HP pavilion laptop.

Thanks,
Deepesh
PS: I can handle terminal so command line tool will do if the options are simple as -r -g -b.

Answer (score 1):

Use xcalib

```
usage:  xcalib [-options] ICCPROFILE
     or xcalib [-options] -alter

where the available options are:
    -display <host:dpy>     or -d
    -screen <screen-#>      or -s
    -clear                  or -c
    -noaction <LUT-size>    or -n
    -verbose                or -v
    -printramps             or -p
    -loss                   or -l
    -invert                 or -i
    -gammacor <gamma>       or -gc
    -brightness <percent>   or -b
    -contrast <percent>     or -co
    -red <gamma> <brightness-percent> <contrast-percent>
    -green <gamma> <brightness-percent> <contrast-percent>
    -blue <gamma> <brightness-percent> <contrast-percent>
    -alter                  or -a
    -help                   or -h
    -version

last parameter must be an ICC profile containing a vcgt-tag

Example: ./xcalib -d :0 -s 0 -v bluish.icc
Example: ./xcalib -red 1.1 10.0 100.0
```

Use the xgamma module to adjust gamma values across RGB.

```
usage:  xgamma [-options]

where the available options are:
    -display host:dpy       or -d
    -quiet                  or -q
    -screen                 or -s
    -version                or -v
    -gamma f.f              Gamma Value
    -rgamma f.f             Red Gamma Value
    -ggamma f.f             Green Gamma Value
    -bgamma f.f             Blue Gamma Value

If no gamma is specified, returns the current setting
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings -> color you should be able to change the color settings of your monitor.
Can not find what you need?

Comment: In Settings there is Device colour profiles, Screen Display and Brighness and lock. Nothing like just color though.

Comment: trying to install gnome color manager